# How can I improve my sklearn logistic regression model

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, python, scikit-learn, accuracy

My objective is to classify sentences into useful (denote in boolean as 1) and not useful (denote in boolean as 0) categories.

I have about 525 features  where 300 features are the most frequent and important keywords after removing stopwords and the rest are domain names.

The total number of documents I have is 793.

I manually labelled the classes as useful and not useful and I have about 93 useful and the rest (700) as not useful.

Below is the result of my logistic regression with the parameter values:

```
model = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)
model = model.fit(X, y)
```

[image]

Based on the results i got, it seems that the regression is doing a very bad job at classifying sentences as useful with really bad precision, recall and 1-score.

How can i improve the accuracy?

Note, as shown above, i already am implementing L1 regularization.

Comment: We don't have enough information to help.
Could you provide a visualization of your points and respective classes? And if possible the boundary of your logistic regressions. That would be a start.

Comment: Your high precision on "non useful" and low precision on "usefull" makes me suspect that your model is optimistic in terms of labelling cases as "non useful".
This might be a side effect of the difference of training examples for each class.
My tip is for you to label/collect a more representative sample of "usefull" data or/and train the model with less "non usefull" examples.